# How do I import modules when using Twisted subprocesses and virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, twisted, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to write a web server in Twisted which takes a user input and draws an image depending on the input.

For the server, I have a simple Twisted web server.
In order to process the image drawing, I am using python [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org).
I am working in a virtualenvwrapper with both Twisted and Wand installed. However, when I run the server I get an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert_bubble.py", line 1, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
ImportError: No module named wand.image
```

If I go to the python interpreter, I can `import twisted` and `import wand.image` fine. I suspect the sub-process isn't using the correct environment. A workaround is to install all the modules that the subprocess uses to my user account, but I would like to avoid that.

The server code is mostly taken from the [Twisted tutorial](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html) page.

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import re

class MyPP(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    def __init__(self, verses):
        self.verses = verses
        self.data = ""
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connectionMade!"
        self.transport.closeStdin() # tell them we're done
    def outReceived(self, data):
        print "outReceived! with %d bytes!" % len(data)
        self.data = self.data + data
    def errReceived(self, data):
        print "errReceived! with %d bytes!" % len(data)
        self.data= self.data+data
    def inConnectionLost(self):
        print "inConnectionLost! stdin is closed! (we probably did it)"
    def outConnectionLost(self):
        print "outConnectionLost! The child closed their stdout!"
        # now is the time to examine what they wrote
        print "I saw them write:", self.data
        #(dummy, lines, words, chars, file) = re.split(r'\s+', self.data)
        #print "I saw %s lines" % lines
    def errConnectionLost(self):
        print "errConnectionLost! The child closed their stderr."
    def processExited(self, reason):
        print "processExited, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,)
    def processEnded(self, reason):
        print "processEnded, status %d" % (reason.value.exitCode,)
        print "quitting"
        reactor.stop()

pp = MyPP(10)
reactor.spawnProcess(pp, sys.executable, ['python', 'insert_bubble.py'], {})
reactor.run()
```

How do I get the subprocess to use the correct virtualenv Python install, and not my home environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running the child process like this:

```
reactor.spawnProcess(
    pp, sys.executable, ['python', 'insert_bubble.py'], {}
)
```

Run it like this:

```
reactor.spawnProcess(
    pp, sys.executable, ['python', 'insert_bubble.py'], os.environ
)
```

This will copy the parent process environment into the child process instead of launching the child process with an empty environment.